# Argument of type '(Promise<Response> | Promise<void>)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(Promise<void> | Promise<Response>)[]'

Tags: typescript

I have this variable - an array of Promises - `(Promise<Response> | Promise<void>)[]`:

```
const promises = [
        this.page.waitForResponse(
          (response) =>
            response.url().includes('/my-account/addressform') &&
            response.status() === ResponseCode.SUCCESS
        ),
        this.page.waitForURL(/.*\/delivery-address\/add$/),
      ];
```

But when I define the function that will receive that array like this:

```
private async loginAgain(promises: (Promise<Response> | Promise<void>)[]) {...}
```

Then I get the error from the compiler:

```
    Argument of type '(Promise<Response> | Promise<void>)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(Promise<void> | Promise<Response>)[]'.
  Type 'Promise<Response> | Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void> | Promise<Response>'.
    Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void> | Promise<Response>'.
      Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
        Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2345)
```

How can I fix this? What should be the right type for the promises parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
I had two different Responses :D
The one I needed is the one from Playwright.

```
import { Response } from '@playwright/test';
```

Sorry!

Comment: That's what I thought at the end - type-wise everything is OK, check out this Typescript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwDboOaoQCCewhAFAA4BO6AtqiAKYgBcM5ACrQ8wDwAlFpUzMAfDAA+MbvUZM+AN3SoAJmICUAbQC6GmAG8AUEYC+JxCgxYa6VQigKAKmPIb2s3s4nGYMakzICNRYnvIAdAEg6NiKTOQQCNjYMKAwThoA3GYmUKLIMLZeIDAAvDBatvaOSirqbgA0hbTVCkIgIhDibjomuATEpBRF8iAaJkA.